# Wrong nearestNeighbor result

Tags: pyqgis

Could somebody tell me what is wrong with this code? This is a part of my script and returns totally different result from "Nearest Hub" with the same line and point layers. I would like to identify the nearest link to each node.

```
lineLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("road links_link")[0]
            spIndex = QgsSpatialIndex() #create spatial index object of links
            feat = QgsFeature()
            feat1 = QgsFeature()
            fit = lineLayer.getFeatures()

            # insert links to index
            while fit.nextFeature(feat1):
                spIndex.insertFeature(feat1)

            while stp.nextFeature(feat):
                pt=feat.geometry().asPoint()
                nearestIds = spIndex.nearestNeighbor(pt,1) # from stop to link
                featureId = nearestIds[0]
                #gets the attributes of the link
                fit2 = lineLayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(featureId)).next()
```

Comment: Could be because the index only looks at the feature bounding box - trying to find a source ...

Answer (score 1):

Spatial indexes will use features bounding box to simplify and speed up things. If you need the correct answer you will need to:

1. Get distance from the nearestFeature returned by the index;
2. Filter up all features inside the bounding box of the feature of interest expanded by the distance calculated previously.
3. Calculate distances from the feature of interest and get the one with the minimum distance.

This will still make use of the index to speed up things.

Comment: The problem is that the code defines a totally different feature as the nearest one.

Comment: Yeah, there are cases it will happen, particularly if you have big irregular features. But the approach I suggested will work even though.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. But why "Nearest hub", which also uses the spatial index, returns the right feature?

Comment: Reading its [code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/HubDistance.py) I see it deals with bounding box's centroids. I didn't check it thoroughly though, I'm in mobile.